# How to display progress for complex Observable?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I wonder how to display progress for complex `Observable` when I use `flatMap` like this:

```
Observable<Int>.from([1,2,3,4])
    .flatMap { queryApi($0) }
    .flatMap { queryApi2($0) }
    .flatMap { queryApi3($0) }
```

I was thinking to use `do` operator:

```
func longOperation() -> Observable<Progress> {

    return Observable.create { observer in
        observer.onNext(.step1)

        let operation = Observable<Int>.from([1,2,3,4])
            .flatMap { queryApi($0) }
            .do(onNext: { _ in observer.onNext(.step2) })
            .flatMap { queryApi2($0) }
            .do(onNext: { _ in observer.onNext(.step3) })
            .flatMap { queryApi3($0) }
            .do(onNext: { _ in observer.onNext(.finished) })
            .subscribe()

        return Disposables.create { operation.dispose() }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to track progress. Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: You know that your `DO` commands will not wait your queryApi finish. So when operation observable emits, your longOperation will receive all steps+finished immediately.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Not true :) `flatMap` prevents from propagating emitted event from `Observable<Int>` to the bottom. Each `queryApi` must emit event before `operation` subscription will receive any. And the result event type of `operation` will be the result type of `queryApi3`. It works, I just wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the way that Krunoslav Zaher implement `ActivityIndicator` in `RxExample` project in RxSwift repository.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/2e64568/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift

Usage:

```swift
let activityIndicator = ActivityIndicator()

let state = githubSearchRepositories(
            searchText: searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.changed.asSignal().throttle(0.3),
            loadNextPageTrigger: loadNextPageTrigger,
            performSearch: { URL in
                GitHubSearchRepositoriesAPI.sharedAPI.loadSearchURL(URL)
                    .trackActivity(activityIndicator)
})
```

So in your case, you can implement another observable similar to `ActivityIndicator`

```swift
let operationProgress = OperationProgress<Progress>()

Observable<Int>.from([1,2,3,4])
    .flatMap { queryApi($0).updateProgress(operationProgress, to: .step1) }
    .flatMap { queryApi2($0).updateProgress(operationProgress, to: .step2) }
    .flatMap { queryApi3($0).updateProgress(operationProgress, to: .step3) }
```

I don't know if that suits your situation, but at least it decouples your progress logic from the operation observable.